# Add Child Element To XML Element using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have an XML document I'm looping through and downloading a file when it exists and saving it to disk.
I want to update the XML file to include the location where I saved the data. How can I best do this?

XML file example:

```
<Invoices xmlns="http://example.com/">
  <invoice>
    <ContractorName>TEST contractor</ContractorName>
    <Invoice_Number>12345</Invoice_Number>
    <Invoice_Date>2017-05-20</Invoice_Date>
    <Invoice_Amount>100.00</Invoice_Amount>
    <Invoice_Hyperlink>https://example.com/path/files/file.pdf</Invoice_Hyperlink>
  </invoice>
  <invoice>
    <ContractorName>TEST contractor 2</ContractorName>
    <Invoice_Number>98765</Invoice_Number>
    <Invoice_Date>2017-05-20</Invoice_Date>
    <Invoice_Amount>1000.00</Invoice_Amount>
  </invoice>
</invoices>
```

My script is as follows for looping through the XML data and saving the file locally.

```
$Invoicesfile = "D:\Download\invoices.xml"
[xml]$Invoice = Get-Content $Invoicesfile -Raw 

$InvoiceDestinationDir = "D:\Invoices_Downloaded\" 

foreach ($r in $Invoice.Invoices.invoice)
{
    If($r.Invoice_Hyperlink -ne $null){

        $Directory = $InvoiceDestinationDir + $r.ContractorName + "\"+ $InvoiceDate.ToString('yyyy') + "\" + $InvoiceDate.ToString('MM-MMM') + "\" + $InvoiceDate.ToString('dd')

        #Test if destination directory exists and create it if it doesn't
        if (!(Test-Path $Directory))
        {
            New-Item $Directory -type directory | Out-Null
        }
        #set destination to destination directory and files name consisting of Jobcode, 
        $destination = $Directory +"\"+  $r.Invoice_Number +"_" + $r.Invoice_Date +  $r.Invoice_Hyperlink.SubString($r.Invoice_Hyperlink.LastIndexOf('.'))

        Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $r.Invoice_Hyperlink -OutFile $destination
   }
}
```

The examples I have found all seem to say use `CreateElement` methond, example below, but I can't get this to work as `$r` in the above example is `System.Xml.XmlLinkedNode` and `CreateElemnt` only seems to be available for `System.Xml.XmlNode`, which would be `$Inovices` but I want the element to be inside `$Invoice.Invoices.invoice`

```
[xml] $doc = Get-Content($filePath)
$child = $doc.CreateElement("newElement")
$doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild($child)
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.The outcome I'd be looking for would be to save the above file with the following content.

```
<Invoices xmlns="http://example.com/">
  <invoice>
    <ContractorName>TEST contractor</ContractorName>
    <Invoice_Number>12345</Invoice_Number>
    <Invoice_Date>2017-05-20</Invoice_Date>
    <Invoice_Amount>100.00</Invoice_Amount>
    <Invoice_Hyperlink>https://example.com/path/files/file.pdf</Invoice_Hyperlink>
    <Local_File>D:\Invoices_Downloaded\12345_2017-05-20.pdf</Local_File>
  </invoice>
  <invoice>
    <ContractorName>TEST contractor 2</ContractorName>
    <Invoice_Number>98765</Invoice_Number>
    <Invoice_Date>2017-05-20</Invoice_Date>
    <Invoice_Amount>1000.00</Invoice_Amount>
  </invoice>
</invoices>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet you found works correctly.
`$Invoice.Invoices.Invoice` is an array containing `XmlLinkedNodes`

Use the `CreateElement()` with your `$Invoice` before your foreach loop.

```
$Invoicesfile = "D:\Download\invoices.xml"
[xml]$Invoice = Get-Content $Invoicesfile -Raw 

$InvoiceDestinationDir = "D:\Invoices_Downloaded\"

$child = $Invoice.CreateElement("Local_File")

foreach ($r in $Invoice.Invoices.Invoice){...}
```

Inside your foreach you can append the `$child` to the Node you actually work on

```
If($r.Invoice_Hyperlink -ne $null){
        $r.appendchild($child)
        $InvoiceDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($r.Invoice_Date, 'yyyy-MM-dd', $null)
```

as you can see, i parsed the date from your xml to be able to use the `$InvoiceDate.ToString()`-method

After Building your `$destination`-Path you can assign that path to your new node with `$r.Local_File = $destination`

Comment: Thanks. This works but when I save the document using $invoice.save() it only saves the last Local_File element. What is the best way to save the amended elements and files. Do I need to save after each `$r.appendchild($child)`

Comment: I'm not sure of the correct method I should be using but what  I did was create a new XML object `[xml]$newXML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Invoices xmlns="http://example.com/"></Invoices>'` and at the end of the loop imported $r to the new XMl object `$newXML.DocumentElement.AppendChild($newXML.ImportNode($r, $true)) | Out-Null` then save the file `$newXML.Save($Invoicesfile)`